# como configurar a IDE eclipse para ler totalmente um projeto laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eclipse

Quando se cria um projeto com composer e importamos para o workspace do eclipse alguns arquivos não aparecem como por exempo o .env .gitignore ou .json alguem sabe como configurar o eclipse para conseguir ler e assim poder escrever nesses arquivos?

Comment: Além da resposta do "scubabbl" Existe um projeto que é um arquivo para qualquer IDE interpretar os métodos magicos do Laravel. E neste projeto fizeram uma pergunta parecida. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No menu de exploração de pacotes (`Package Explorer`), no topo direito tem uma seta apontando para baixo chamada `View Menu` (basta passar o mouse em cima para ver a ToolTip mostrando o nome do botão). No menu que apareceu, vá até a opção de Filtros (`Filters`) e remova o recurso `.*`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo:

```
Package Explorer -> View Menu (seta pra baixo) -> Filters -> remova .*
```

> Por: [scubabbl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98610/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-show-files)

Comment: muito bom, resposta correta pela resposta